# Apply regex on uri label of prometheus metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I would like to plot the external API count in a graph but few of the external GET api's had query params. I would like to consider all request for a `x` API with query params as same and increase the request count. Here is my promql:

```
sum(rate(http_client_requests_seconds_count{app="$application", uri!~".*actuator.*"}[2m])) by (method, uri)
```

Currently all requests with different query params are considered as separate requests and increases respective count. Can we apply some regex like `uri=~"([^?]+)"` on the label uri for this? Please assist on this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply filter out params, since you want an aggregation. You'll need to specify the way of aggregation for Prometheus.

This can be done with use of [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) to introduce "parameterless" uri label, and aggregation based on it:

```
sum by (method, clean_uri) (
 label_replace(
  rate(http_client_requests_seconds_count{app="$application", uri!~".*actuator.*"} [2m]),
  "clean_uri","$1",
  "uri","([^?]+).*"
)
```

`label_replace` is used to introduce into result of `rate` function call a new label `clean_uri`. It that will contain everything from `uri` label until question mark.

Then same aggregation as before is used, but instead of `uri`, `clean_uri` is being used.

Comment: Hi @markalex Thanks for the prompt response. I have tested the above promql but issue is it is only considering the count of base endpoint with aggregating the results after removing the query params.
Ex:- 
Before 
/api/test/abc                     -  5 (request count)
/api/test/abc?x=1&y=2     -  2
/api/test/abc?x=4             -  1

Expected:
/api/test/abc                     -  8

Actual (with above promql mentioned)
/api/test/abc                     -  5

Kindly assist on this, thanks

Comment: @Rajeev, this shouldn't happen. Please check that you used correct labels in you `sum by` clause. Also please see the output of the query without `sum by` aggregation